# Set exception on promise without using std::current_exception

Tags: c++, exception, promise

In [C++ reference regarding the `set_exception` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception) , the example uses `std::current_exception`. To do that you have to throw and catch your exception:

```cpp
    std::thread t([&p]{
        try {
            // code that may throw
            throw std::runtime_error("Example");
        } catch(...) {
            try {
                // store anything thrown in the promise
                p.set_exception(std::current_exception());
                // or throw a custom exception instead
                // p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(MyException("mine")));
            } catch(...) {} // set_exception() may throw too
        }
    });
```

This throwing and catching is obviously tedious, but the method accepts a `std::exception_ptr`. I was wondering whether it's possible to set a specific exception directly. I imagine the problem would be that a local exception object would have lifetime issues if we pass around a pointer to its address and allocating a new exception object would leave memory leaks. Is there a way ?

Comment: _"was wondering whether it's possible to set a specific exception directly"_ you have it done in your comments: `p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(MyException("mine")));`.  _" I imagine the problem would be that a local exception object would have lifetime issues"_ it won't.

Comment: @ixSci that essentially does a try-throw-catch https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/make_exception_ptr

Comment: And? You don't like a tedious method so the Standard provides you with a convenient one. Its implementation is the only one possible.

Comment: @ixSci And I want to avoid the overhead of throwing and catching. That's my intention to begin with. Writing it more succinctly is certainly good, just wondering if there's a better way. Also I doubt "throwing and catching" is the only way, e.g. I can always allocate my own exceptions and set them outside a try-catch block; I'd expect the standard library has a better way than me doing the memory management for that.

Comment: @ixSci But maybe `make_exception_ptr` can do what is best in each situation. So I'll make sure to use that and if no other idea comes up I'll leave it as is

Comment: There is no other way except allocating memory from the heap but that isn't the most reliable way of implementing things, given we might be in the `std::bad_alloc` catch.